# Vue form select emit event when the same element is selected

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuejs2

When I attach the '@change' property to a form input, e.g.

```
<select v-model="data" @change="handler">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
```

It is only triggered when a different option is selected. How do I trigger the handler function even when the same option is chosen again?

Comment: You might get better responses if you explain _why_ you need to capture this event.

Comment: I don't believe that `select` is designed for this behaviour, or can even be reliably customised across environments to handle your requirement.

Comment: @Phil, I have requirements for some customized form content. Selecting an option loads some information. The user can change the information, and when they re-select the option, the information should be reloaded or at least some feedback needs to be given.

Answer (score 2):

The event that's triggered on a `<select>` when selecting the already selected `<option>` is `mouseup`.

Therefore, you'll need an additional prop to store the select's state (`isOpen`). You'll call a helper method (let's name it `mouseUp`) and only call `handler()` when the select is closing.
For all the other input cases (keypress and whatnot), rely on `@input`.
I added another helper prop to avoid triggering `handler()` twice:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    data: 1,
    isOpen: false,
    changed: false
  }),
  methods: {
    mouseUp(e) {
      if (this.isOpen) {
        this.$nextTick().then(() => {
          if (!this.changed){
            this.handler(e);
          }
        });
        this.isOpen = false;
      } else {
        this.changed = false;
        this.isOpen = true;
      }
    },
    handler(e) {
      this.changed = true;
      console.log(`handler(${e.target.value})`);
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="data" @mouseup="mouseUp" @input="handler">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The logic might seem cumbersome but, because `@input` is triggered before `@mouseup`, I'm only calling `handler()` from `mouseUp()` if `@input` has not been triggered and the `<select>` is closing.

The only case of `<select>` closing and `handler()` not being fired is pressing ESC key when select is open. But I'm not sure you should be calling it in that case (user wants to cancel any change). If you want to call it in that case as well, it's quite easy to listen to that specific case.

Comment: What about when the user is not using a mouse, ie keyboard navigation?

Comment: @Phil, have you tested it?

Comment: Admittedly no and I see now that it does seem to work, at least in Chrome. Not so good in Firefox though, it doesn't trigger the `mouseUp` handler and there's also an issue with `e.path`

Comment: @Phil, In FF it failed *because* of `e.path`. I changed it to `e.target.value`. Well spotted.

Comment: Dang, FF calls `mouseup` first. Bummer! I'll have to come back at this with a better solution. Too tired now, I'll call it a day.